# Which element is the 'middle' in a B-Tree of even order?

Tags: b-tree

If I have an B-Tree of **order 4** with the following data in it...

[image: btree]

and I need to add 2 to the tree; do I...

1. add the 2 to the node (making it invalid, as it now has 4 keys), then split the node, taking the value 2 as the middle value and propagating it up

OR

2. do I not add the 2, take 3 as the middle value, propagate 3 up, then add 2 into the correct node?

Excuse the poor diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You perform the first option. For a B-tree of any order you always add the node then perform splits that propagate upwards. For a great interactive demonstration of a variety of basic (insert, delete, search) operations on data structures, there is a useful algorithm visualization page I go to located [here](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Algorithms.html). Find the B-tree page and you will find that it performs option 1.

Comment: Great thanks, it looks like the lecture slides I'm looking at have done it wrong then. They showed 3 getting propagated to the top.

Comment: @CSStudent I think they might have done option 1 but just propagated the 3 instead of the 2. I don't have a proof of this but I believe you can take either one since they are both "middle" values; it just makes the resulting tree look slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

How to find which element to push upward:

1)Push the element in proper position of Btree and check if overflow occurs.

If then follow steps 2 and 3 given below.

2)find CEILING`((order of Btree+1)/2`).

3)Move that index element upward giving two pointers to left and right subtree.

Note:First insert the element then follow steps 2 and 3 if overflow occurs.

Here in this example first insert 2.

The partial leaf of the tree becomes |1| 2| 3| 5|.

overflow occurs because only 3 keys can there be in any node.

Find ceiling ((4+1)/2)= ceiling(5/2)= 3 (index no)

3rd index value 3 is the middle element. so propagate it up. 3's left pointer points to 1|2 and right points to 5.